# Laravel View Composer equivalent in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I'm learning django 2.1 is their any method in django which is equivalent to Laravel `View::composer()` method share data into specific templates.

secondly how can i share data across different templates in django project which are frequently used.

### Note

`You might advise storing data in session but i'm looking for other solutions`

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Laravel docs say "View composers are callbacks or class methods that are called when a view is rendered.". In django speak these would be called views - class-based or function-based.
2. If you have data that you need in several different templates, consider writing a context processor - they can add data to every context passed to your templates.

Comment: `context processor` something new will go through it in django documentation. Consider i have menus common to all templates in this case does `context processor` solve my problem.

Comment: if your *templates* have common parts, I'd rather recommend template inheritance or the include tag. Context processors just supply data to the templates.

Comment: ` Context processors just supply data `  that what I needed to supply data to common templates. Thank you.